# Cannot find username folder (game path)

Tags: games, directory

In the game launcher for minecraft, it tells me that the game directory is in /home/smith/.minecraft, but when I go to home, there is not folder named 'smith'

I am new to ubuntu, and other questions I've seen I cannot understand due to this, even if they do answer my problem.

The game runs fine, I just cannot find the directory due to the 'smith' folder being non existent from what I can see.

Comment: what's the output of: `whoami` and `ls -lhs /home/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`smith` is your Username. If you open the Home directory, it should get into `/home/smith` directory. Because the value assigned to `HOME` variable is `/home/smith`.

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/smith
```

You can check the existence of `smith` directory inside `/home` by running the below commands,

```
$ cd /home
$ ls
smith
```

And also you can't see `.minecraft` file, because it's hidden. File-name preceded with `.`, will makes the corresponding file to hide automatically. You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view those hidden files.